# Why is Facebook scope not being used in Django AllAuth?

Tags: python, django, facebook

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'facebook': { 
        'SCOPE': ['email', 'publish_stream'],
        'METHOD': 'oauth2' ,
        'LOCALE_FUNC': lambda request: return 'zh_CN'
    } 
}

SOCIALACCOUNT_QUERY_EMAIL = ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED
```

I have specified in local settings of Django AllAuth about the scope of authorisation but none of these are being used when forming the login url ?

Answer (score 0):

It was my bad, when you save the allauth settings in local_settings.py it was never actually used as the main django conf missed the line :

```
from local_settings import *
```